# Where does $2^4 + 2^2 + 2^0=1 + 2*(2*(1+2*2))$ come from?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Where does the following equation come from?  I am trying to understand it.

$2^4 + 2^2 + 2^0=1 + 2*(2*(1+2*2))$

Or the "extended" version

$2^4 + 2^2 + 2^0=1 + 2 * (0 + 2 * (1 + 2 * (0 + 2)))$

but of course zero can be omitted.

@edit

I have second questio, how can I write any number using this method?

I mean for example 10 or 6

Comment: You can rewrite things however you like so long as they are equal.  This is to me like asking "Where does $8=5+3=1+1+6$ come from?"  Why did I choose $1+1+6$ at the end?  Totally arbitrarily.  As for your specific problem, the specific way of rewriting seems to mirror that of [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method), letting $2$ play the role of $x$ here.  $1+x^2+x^4=1+x(0+x(1+x(0+x)))$

Comment: Let $x=2^2$ in $1 + x + x^2 = 1 + x(1 +x)$.

Comment: Second question: you can write any number in binary. With that, I also gave you the way *how* to do it.

Comment: for example 6 is 110 and what next? how can I write using horner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2^4 + 2^2 + 2^0 =\\
2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2 + 2\cdot2 + 1 =\\
2 (2\cdot2\cdot2 + 2) + 1 =\\
2 (2 (2\cdot2 + 1)) + 1$$

Comment: @Kanashimi if your issue was solved, consider accepting an answer so as to close this question

Answer (score 1):

$1+2*(2*(1+2*2))=1+2^2(1+2^2)=1+2^2+2^2*2^2=2^0+2^2+2^4$